# Number of elements not equal to their inverses is even number

Tags: group-theory

In any finite group, number of elements not equal to their own inverses is even number

In my book they have paired elements with their inverses, being elements and inverses different from each other. How do i see this hint ? Thanks

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: you can divide such elements into pairs: $(a,a^{-1})$.

Comment: @almagest You can also try and prove it by contradiction-if I got puzzled on an exam and blanked out,that's what I'd try.

Comment: @almagest so i have to count both $a$ and $a^{-1}$

Comment: @almagest if there are $k$ pairs then $2k$ elements are there

Comment: @Gathdi If $a\ne a^{-1}$ then $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are *different* elements, so yes you have to count them both!

Comment: @almagest but this is not satisfying. How can i be sure that group is partitioned into k  pairs

Comment: It isn't, there might be any number of elements which are their own inverse. But the elements which are not their own inverse *are* grouped into pairs.

Comment: @almagest Thanks

Comment: @almagest why cannot be it that there are 3 elements {a,b,c} such that inverse of a is b and inverse of b is c

Comment: @Gathdi Maybe because inverses are unique, if $b$ is the inverse of $a$, then $a$ is the inverse of $b$.

Comment: @sqtrat hmm. this is quite confusing

Comment: $b=a^{-1},b^{-1}=c$. Multiplying the lhs together and the rhs together we get $1=a^{-1}c$. Multiplying by $a$ we get $a=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ H \subseteq G$, such that, $ h \neq h^{-1} $ for all $ h \in H $. Since the inverse of an element is distinct from itself, you can pair every element, $ h $, with a distinct element, $ h^{-1} $, giving you an even list of elements.